# The `\label` command defined by `cleveref` fails in a `thm-restate` environment

Tags: cleveref, thmtools

As reported [here](https://github.com/leo-colisson/proof-at-the-end/issues/3), it seems not possible to use the optional argument of `\label` (version defined by `cleveref`) together with the `thm-restate` package. Any idea what's wrong?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}[Lemma not restated]
  \label[lemma]{lemma:restated}
  Not an issue if not restated.
\end{lemma}

But when restated\dots
\begin{restatable}[Lemma restated]{lemma}{myname}
  \label[lemma]{lemma:myname}
  Hello
\end{restatable}
\dots it gives strange output:
\myname*

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

[`thmtools` v0.69 2020-07-16](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.18.1595086955.2548.ctan-ann@ctan.org) has contained the following patch, and I've been the new maintainer of it now.

---

This is a compatibility issue between `cleveref` and `thm-restate`.

- Inside `restatable` environment, specific commands are ignored. `\label` is one of them.
- In LaTeX2e flavor, `\label` accepts only one mandatory argument, so it is ignored by `\let\label\@gobble` (inside the definition of `thmt@restatable` environment, in `thm-restate.sty`)
- But `cleveref` package extends the `\label` to accept two arguments with the first optional.
- Hence `restatable` now only ignores `[` in usage `\label[lemma]{lemma:restated}`, and leaves `lemma]{lemma:restated}` in the output.

The following example shows a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{cleveref}{
  \xpatchcmd\thmt@restatable
    {\let\label=\@gobble}
    {\let\label=\gobbled@cleveref@label}
    {}{\fail}
  
  \newcommand\gobbled@cleveref@label[2][]{}
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}[Lemma not restated]
  \label[lemma]{lemma:restated}
  Not an issue if not restated.
\end{lemma}

But when restated\dots
\begin{restatable}[Lemma restated]{lemma}{myname}
  \label[lemma]{lemma:myname}
  Hello
\end{restatable}
\dots it gives strange output:
\myname*

\cref{lemma:myname}
\end{document}
```

[image]